# Webform E-mail send to selected user

Tags: users, webforms, emails

When the user is fill out my webform they are going be asked "who refer you to this page." The user would pick a user. I want to be able to send the results e-mail to that person programatically once they have submitted their question.

So I'm looking for a module allow me to e-mail the webform results base on  "who refer you to this page."?

Comment: You should try writing a Template for Webform

Comment: @darol are you having select list for user selection?

Comment: Yes @DEVARAJJOHNSON I'm using a select list. However, currently this is not connected to the user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) along with [user_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7) is your answer

something like this:

```
function hook_node_presave($node) {
if($node->type == 'webform') {

$uid = user_load($node->FIELDOFUID);

$uid->mail;

// do your mail send here with $uid->mail;

}

}
```